# Initialize and call a common form

Tags: c#, winforms

I know the title is misleading, but I could not think of a better for this problem.  I have a program that displays a form to allow the user to select from other programs to run.  Then I am trying to create some common code to call a form.   Not sure the best approach without duplicating the code.  Here is what I am trying to do;

```
        TaxYearForm loTaxYear = new TaxYearForm();

        var loTaxProgram = new BaseForm();

        if (loTaxYear.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string lsTaxModule = loTaxYear.gsTaxModule.ToUpper();
            int lnTaxYear = loTaxYear.gnPrimaryFilter;

            switch (lsTaxModule)
            {
                case "RE":
                    RealEstateForm loTaxProgram = new RealEstateForm();

                    break;
                case "PC":
                    PerCapitaForm loTaxProgram = new PerCapitaForm();

                    break;

            }

            loTaxProgram.gsUserId = gsUserId;
            loTaxProgram.gnPrimaryFilter = lnTaxYear;
            loTaxProgram.gnSecurityLevel = gnSecurityLevel;

            loTaxProgram.ShowDialog();
```

I cannot do this because inside the switch statement I re-purpose the variable loTaxProgram.  I can put all the code inside each case statement, but that is what I want to avoid.  I created a method inside a class,but had the same problem since I had to declare the parameter as a BaseForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new factory class to create the form:

```
public class FormFactory
{
    public BaseFrom Create(string taxCode)
    {
        switch (taxCode)
        {
            case "RE":
                return new RealEstateForm();

                // rest of stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

So you're code could look like this:

```
if (loTaxYear.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{    
    var factory = new FormFactory();

    var loTaxProgram = factory.Create(loTaxYear.gsTaxModule.ToUpper());

    loTaxProgram.gsUserId = gsUserId;
    loTaxProgram.gnPrimaryFilter = loTaxYear.gnPrimaryFilter;
    loTaxProgram.gnSecurityLevel = gnSecurityLevel;

    loTaxProgram.ShowDialog();
}
```

So it will be the factory class' responsibility to create a form, making things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in further re-declaration

```
switch (lsTaxModule)
{
  case "RE":
    loTaxProgram = new RealEstateForm();

    break;
  case "PC":
    loTaxProgram = new PerCapitaForm();

    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If both your forms derive from your BaseForm then dont redeclare your `loTaxProgram` variable.

```
        TaxYearForm loTaxYear = new TaxYearForm();

        BaseFrom loTaxProgram;

        if (loTaxYear.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string lsTaxModule = loTaxYear.gsTaxModule.ToUpper();
            int lnTaxYear = loTaxYear.gnPrimaryFilter;

            switch (lsTaxModule)
            {
                case "RE":
                    loTaxProgram = new RealEstateForm();

                    break;
                case "PC":
                    loTaxProgram = new PerCapitaForm();

                    break;

            }

            loTaxProgram.gsUserId = gsUserId;
            loTaxProgram.gnPrimaryFilter = lnTaxYear;
            loTaxProgram.gnSecurityLevel = gnSecurityLevel;

            loTaxProgram.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to do this (note the change in the case statements):

```
    TaxYearForm loTaxYear = new TaxYearForm(); 

    var loTaxProgram = new BaseForm(); 

    if (loTaxYear.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        string lsTaxModule = loTaxYear.gsTaxModule.ToUpper(); 
        int lnTaxYear = loTaxYear.gnPrimaryFilter; 

        switch (lsTaxModule) 
        { 
            case "RE": 
                loTaxProgram = new RealEstateForm(); 

                break; 
            case "PC": 
                loTaxProgram = new PerCapitaForm();

                break; 

        } 

        loTaxProgram.gsUserId = gsUserId; 
        loTaxProgram.gnPrimaryFilter = lnTaxYear; 
        loTaxProgram.gnSecurityLevel = gnSecurityLevel; 

        loTaxProgram.ShowDialog();
```

For future reference, you might want to google the factory pattern which would suit this sort of code quite nicely IMO.